# FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() is returning null value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

`FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` is returning `null` value. Previously my code worked fine but since couple of days its returning `currentUser` as `null`.

Also I've tried my app on another device and in that device everything is working fine with the same code.

```
mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mCurrentUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser()
mUserDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                              .child(mCurrentUser.getUid());
```

Exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.String
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object
>   reference

I have already tried erasing app data and uninstalling and reinstalling my app on my device but nothing worked.

Is there a problem with my device or `Firebase`?

Comment: Can you go to your Firebase Users Table and confirm that you have that user? Also, are you doing this after signing in?

Comment: yes user already exists. i've checked it there, as i have said everything is working fine in another device

Comment: You have to sign in first before trying to get the user!  The problem seems to be that your user is not yet signed in!!

Comment: How do I sign in when my app is crashing in the first place.

Comment: You seem you have a lack in understanding the basic concept of how to use `Firebase` Database. You should read more about [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the user isn't signed into your app, which causes `mCurrentUser.getUid()` to throw an exception.

The solution is to only call `getUid()` is there is a signed-in yser:

```
mCurrentUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (mCurrentUser != null) {
    mUserDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                          .child(mCurrentUser.getUid());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem. but i still cant understand why my previous code was working fine in my another device.

Comment: My guess is the user was signed in there, and here you have no signed in user.